# UTC Conversion to User Timezone with Daylight Savings Time

Tags: php, mysql, utc, dst, convert-tz

OK I got my mySql timezone package installed from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html

I'm also storing all my times with `UTC_TIMESTAMP();`

And my little tidbit of code:

```
$_SESSION['user_tz'] = 'America/New_York';
$last = "CONVERT_TZ(p.posted_on, 'UTC', '{$_SESSION['user_tz']}')";
```

I get back `UTC/GMT -5 hours` which is an hour ahead because of daylight savings time (DST)

I've been checking searching stack overflow and google for a few hours now, still not quite sure how to work around this. I'm really confused as to how to work around this? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Although this is not exactly what you're looking for, I usually make all the time conversions by Javascript, so that each user sees the time interpreted to their timezones.

Answer (score 0):

write

```
 date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: thanks, i figured it out, apparently my PC clock was not synced